# How to create a dynamic number of possibly children objects using partial views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a parent object that contains a property that is a list of children objects.  I'd like to have it so that when the form loads to create the parent object a partial view is used to create the list of child objects.

The problem is I have to idea how to have the list of children object populated.  I can do one object ok, but a dynamic list of possible children is difficult.  Any ideas?

@Html.RenderPartial("_CreateChild", Model.Children);

```
public class Parent
{
    private List<Child> _list;

    public Guid Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<Child> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _list;
        }
        set
        {
            _list = value;
        }
    }

    public Parent()
    {
        _list = new List<Child>();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the partial view doesn't know what type the children is, then what is it you want the partial view to do with them?

Comment: @AFinkelstein I'm looking to possibly changing the Partial view to a EditorTemplate.  I'd like them to be able to create the child objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parent view you could have a foreach loop that calls the partial view and passes a single child object at a time, for example :

```
@foreach(var _child in Children) {
  @Html.RenderPartial("_CreateChild", _child);
}
```

If the child list is large this may not be a great option but it should be fine if your list is < 100.